# Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top query

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

If you look at http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-push/

There are two styles of the navbar if you adjust your browser size.  On large screens it's just the button icon:
[image]

On medium to smaller screens the navbar has a background color and bottom border:
[image]

I'm trying to get all screen sizes to have the styled background but can't for the life of me work out which style or media-query I need to change?  Any help gratefully received!

Comment: Add your code in the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Chrome, go to the Developer Tools (F12) while the page is on the large screen mode, and take a look at the Computed section for your navbar. If you look at the background-color tag, you will see it is set to rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), and next to that it shows where it gets this from (in this case, navmenu-push.css). If you follow that link, you can see the media queries for small and large screens, and you can see the large screen media query sets the background to none (as well as setting other styles).

Try removing this section from navmenu-push.css:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar {
    right: auto;
    background: none;
    border: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it, I've never used the computed tab before, will do from now on!   Cheers